# Assistance with factory pattern implementation

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I’ve tagged this question PHP, but it’s more a question on design patterns, namely the factory pattern; PHP is just the programming language I’m using.

I’m building an estate agents’ (“real estate” for American cousins) website. I have a `Property` class, but then other classes that extend this, i.e. `LettingProperty`, `CommercialProperty` that has fields specific to that type of property.

In my controller I want to display a particular property. This is easy as I pass the property ID as a parameter. My approach is to then create a factory class that returns the property as an instance of the relevant class. For example, if the property with an ID of 1 is a letting property, return an instance of `LettingProperty`. If it’s just a standard “for sale” property, an instance of `Property`.

How can I go about this? I created a `PropertyFactory` class and implemented a method called `buildFromId()`, but having trouble on creating an elegant solution to:

- Find the relevant record in my `properties` database table
- Do any `LEFT JOIN`s (i.e. if it’s a letting property left join the relevant data from `letting_properties` (foreign key: `property_id`)
- Return the resultant data, as an instance of the corresponding class

Is a factory approach the correct design pattern for this scenario? And if so, how could I go about the above?

Comment: it looks like you have more problems with database than with factory pattern..so how is your db design? why are you facing problems with left join?

Comment: @redreggae he doesn't know what table to join to when he is issuing the query as Property can be a Raw Property that has no joins, a LettingProperty that would join to one table or a CommercialProperty that would join to a different table.

Comment: @martinBean It might be simpler to just issue two queries, one for the property and one for the property subtype based on the value contained within the property_type field.... to help with performance caching the results might be an appropriate action.

Comment: @martinbean Having the  factory return a decorated (ie the Decorator Pattern) Property might be a good solution.

Comment: @Orangepill Exactly. I don’t know which table (if any) to join based on the ID alone. I’d rather stick to one database query if possible. I can `LEFT JOIN` the tables (and they’ll return null if no data exists in joining tables) but I’d like a clean method of converting this raw DB result to the relevant model class.

Comment: also look for `party data model` and `supertype subtype`

Answer (score 0):

If you already can produce a query that variably flattens the the tree using left joins then you can do something like this on the php side to create your object model. Of course you would want to fill out the implementation a more on the property types for them to really be useful.

```
 class Property {
    public function setPropertyValuesFromArray($array){
        foreach($array as $k=>$v){
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
 }

 class CommercialProperty extends Property {}
 class LettingProperty extends Property {}

 class PropertyFactory {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(DbConnection $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function getPropertyById($id){
        $result = $this->db->fetchRow($queryToGetPropertyById);
        return $this->getPropertyFromArray($result);
    }
    public function getPropertyFromArray($result){
        switch($result["property_type"]){
            case "residential":
                $p = new Property();
                break;
            case "commericial":
                $p = new CommercialProperty();
                break;
            case "letting":
                $p = new LettingProperty();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown Property Type ".$result["property_type"]);
                break;
        }
        $p->setPropertyValueFromArray($result);
        return $p;
    }
 }
```